# Does outlook 2016 (desktop) support SSO with add-ins?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

## Does outlook 2016 (desktop) support SSO with add-ins?

I can't use `OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken` and `Office.auth.getAccessToken` in desktop outlook client.(error with undefined)

##### Systeminfo:

- Windows 10 Enterprise(19044.1706)
- Microsoft Outlook 2016( **16.0.5197.1000**) MSO(**16.0.5278.1000**) 32bit
  (Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016)

Comment: Hi, 
It looks like you whre/are working on a similar topic as I am. Did you solve your issue with sso and Outlook 2016? If yes feel free to contact me at benedict@digitalwright.eu

Answer (score 0):

SSO requires Identity API set 1.3. To require this API set in your Outlook add-in code, check if it's supported by calling `isSetSupported('IdentityAPI', '1.3')`. Declaring it in the Outlook add-in's manifest isn't supported. You can also determine if the API is supported by checking that it's not undefined.

The following table lists the Identity API requirement sets, the Office client applications that support that requirement set, and the build or version numbers for the Office application.

[image: requirements for Single-sign on in Outlook]

If you are working with an Outlook add-in, be sure to enable Modern Authentication for the Microsoft 365 tenancy. For information about how to do this, see [Exchange Online: How to enable your tenant for modern authentication](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32711.exchange-online-how-to-enable-your-tenant-for-modern-authentication.aspx).